# Grouping ID-identified pages in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I've been tasked to generate more useful data out of our google analytics account.

We have URL paths that include the ID of a given object, say a product, workspace, or device. So routes could look like

`/ide/products/8a8985cf-8a74-ee7a-a9a3-d1335a4a7ad6/workspaces/987dd13e-57a3-353b-2b42-db58c479d0ca/draft/devices/40000c2a69109dd8`

`/ide/products/531743df-3d77-ec6b-4014-d33925639743/workspaces/e0eb62fc-e7d2-56ec-56cf-79ae53714de3/draft`

`/ide/products/65bc6914-4ddd-1718-0d47-e91b0ff1dff1/workspaces/f7b526ad-7e5c-7f11-f4ad-bb53f8e583d7/draft`

`/ide/products/65bc6914-4ddd-1718-0d47-e91b0ff1dff1/workspaces/f7b526ad-7e5c-7f11-f4ad-bb53f8e583d7/deployments`

Following the pattern `/ide/products/{{product_id}}/workspaces/{{workspace_id}}/{{page}}` , among other things.

In "Behavior Flow," I'm trying to show how users navigate from `/ide` to `/ide/products` to `ide/products/{{any_product_id}}/workspaces` to `ide/products/{{any_product_id}}/workspaces/{{any_workspaces_id}}/draft` but am unclear how to create groupings that ignore arbitrary IDs. I've tried "Content Groupings" but those seem to be more high-level than what I'm looking for, in that I must "select" one as a top-level filter in the behavior flow chart (as opposed to "automatic groupings").

How can I demonstrate user flow that is identical regardless of the actual ID of the object being "plugged into" a given page? How do I see charts in Google Analytics that treat

`/ide/products/65bc6914-4ddd-1718-0d47-e91b0ff1dff1/workspaces/f7b526ad-7e5c-7f11-f4ad-bb53f8e583d7/draft`

`/ide/products/531743df-3d77-ec6b-4014-d33925639743/workspaces/e0eb62fc-e7d2-56ec-56cf-79ae53714de3/draft`

as the same route?

EDIT: Another example: I'm looking at behavior > Page Timings, with Primary Dimension set to "Page." I'm seeing `/ide/products/{{id_1}}/workspaces/{{workspace_1}}/draft` and `/ide/products/{{id_2}}/workspaces/{{workspace_2}}/draft` as separate entities, when ideally they would be treated as a single entity, as page load time is affected by the application features on that page (which are universal regardless of the given ID).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can totally get this done by using event tracking. Not sure how well your Javascript knowledge but here is what I've done for projects that I've worked on.

### 1. Implement event tracking

Use Javascript to send event based on page, user actions or whatever event. Read simple guide from Google https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events .
In your case, you will need to have Javascript code in the four pages and send event according to the page users are loading. They look something like this:

#### IDE page

```
gtag('event', 'ide', {
  'event_category': 'page_load',
  'event_label': 'Google'
});
```

#### Products page

```
gtag('event', 'products', {
  'event_category': 'page_load',
  'event_label': 'Google'
});
```

#### Wordspaces page

```
gtag('event', 'products', {
  'event_category': 'page_load',
  'event_label': 'Google'
});
```

#### Workspaces page

```
gtag('event', 'workspaces', {
  'event_category': 'page_load',
  'event_label': 'Google'
});
```

### 2. Viewing event flow

After implementing and making sure that Google receiving events. Open `Google Analytics dashboard > Behaviors > Events > Event Flow`

Enjoy the result!

Comment: I am so sorry I missed granting you the bounty on this, I underwent surgery and totally forgot! Thank you for this answer.

Comment: aww. Wish you the best!